# Android: How to get boolean result from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, connection

I want to check Internet connectivity in my App. I found a code but I don't know how to use since I'm really a beginner.

My code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //I want something like this.
            if(InternetCheck==true){
                Toast("You are connected to internet")
            }
            else{
            Toast("Connection Failed")
            }

    }

 static class InternetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

        private Consumer mConsumer;
        public  interface Consumer { void accept(Boolean internet); }

        public  InternetCheck(Consumer consumer) { mConsumer = consumer; execute(); }

        @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) { try {
            Socket sock = new Socket();
            sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 1500);
            sock.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) { return false; } }

        @Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean internet) { mConsumer.accept(internet); }
    }
```

But I don't know how to get a boolean result from AsyncTask. Please teach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new InternetCheck(new InternetCheck.Consumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Boolean connected) {
        if (connected) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Internet is connected");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Internet is not connected");
        }     
    }
}).execute();
```

Comment: It give me error.  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.

Comment: I removed execute() and it work like charm thank you

Comment: It is using an interface, I use this without execute()

Answer (score 0):

You can get result from `AsyncTask` by using `get()`:

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Boolean result = new InternetCheck().execute().get();
                if (result == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You are connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else { 
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
```

Or you can check boolean result in `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean internet) { 
        mConsumer.accept(internet);
        if (internet == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "You are connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else { 
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }
```